# Why doesn't IE listen to ActiveX events?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, atl, connection-points

I put ActiveX control onto HTML page with longrun method that should fire events to be processed by IE.

They don't fire because `m_vec.GetSize() == 0`, it means IE doesn't connect to my ActiveX.

Site is localhost, it's in Trusted sites and security level is set to minimum.

Html

```
 <object id="myObj" name="myObj" ...>                    
 </object>   

   <script type="text/javascript" for="myObj" event="CallbackMethod(...)" language="javascript">
        alert("hello!");
    </script>
```

IDL

```
[uuid(...), dual]
interface _IBasicEvents : IDispatch
{   
    [id(1)] HRESULT CallbackMethod(...);
};

[uuid(...)] 
coclass MyService
{       
    [default] interface IBasicInterface;        
    [default, source] dispinterface _IBasicEvents;
};
```

С++ inheritance list:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMyService :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>, 
    public CComControl<CMyService>, 
    public CComCoClass<CMyService, &CLSID_MyService>,
    public IConnectionPointContainerImpl<CMyService>,       
    public IObjectWithSiteImpl<CMyService>,     
    public IPersistPropertyBagImpl<CMyService>, 
    public IObjectSafetyImpl<CMyService, INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER | INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA>,
    public IOleInPlaceObjectWindowlessImpl<CMyService>,
    public IOleObjectImpl<CMyService>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IBasicInterface, ...>,
    public CProxy_IScannerServiceEvents<CMyService>
```

COM_MAP

```
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IBasicInterface)
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IConnectionPointContainer)
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IObjectWithSite)    
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IOleObject) 
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IObjectSafety)  
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IPersistPropertyBag)
```

CONNECTION_POINT_MAP

```
CONNECTION_POINT_ENTRY(__uuidof(_IBasicEvents))
```

CATEGORY_MAP

```
IMPLEMENTED_CATEGORY(CATID_SafeForScripting)
IMPLEMENTED_CATEGORY(CATID_SafeForInitializing)
```

What is wrong here ? Why IE doesn't connect to my connection point interface?

**Temporary Solution**

I abandoned games with `<script for event>` and start to pass javascript callback function as method parameter (type `IDispatch*`)

Comment: Shouldn't it be just event="CallbackMethod"  ?

Answer (score 0):

> [uuid(...), dual] **interface** _IBasicEvents : IDispatch
>
> [default, source] **dispinterface** _IBasicEvents;

AFAIK IDL coclass should reference event interface, as you do above, but your _IBasicEvents is not defined as dispainterface. Instead it is a real interface, which is not correct. There should be:

> [ ... ] dispinterface _IBasicEvents { methods: ... };